# Is there a way to do a "breakpoint" where a variable is changed in PhpStorm or IntelliJ?

Tags: debugging, phpstorm

I'm working on a new complex codebase and there seems to be hundreds of function calls in it. I know I want to see where a variable `data['total']` changes but I cannot seem to pinpoint what line it changes in due to the complexity.

Is there anyway to find the line responsible for the change? My current setup has PhpStorm and Xdebug and it works fine but it's taking a long time to trace through without knowing where to look.

Comment: Not possible with PhpStorm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7993

Comment: What is `$data`? Plain array? Here is some idea .. that may not be suitable for your codebase, but still .... Can you **temporarily** replace it by some object that implements `\ArrayAccess` interface? You could then watch `offsetSet()` method (have breakpoint inside it) and see when `total` gets updated and then look at the stack trace.